# Custom options below pages/posts editor?

Tags: themes, custom-field, customization, theme-options

I want to add permanently boxes below Visual/HTML editor for each page/post. I've never played with custom fields before, and I'm not sure is it way to go?

If yes ten tell me, good people of StackExchange, how to achieve something like that (grey boxes):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for custom meta fields, which you can style anyway you want using CSS.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

You would either have to write your own functions to accomplish this or use one of the many custom fields plugins, I would recommend the WPAlchemy MetaBox.

Comment: so I should definitely use add_post_meta()? Codex says it always needs a post ID so I'm not sure how to attach my boxes to more than one? And what if I want different set of metaboxes for pages, posts and custom post types? Thank you!

Comment: I guess you made a mistake and I'm looking for add_meta_box() instead of meta fields, right? :)

Comment: Yes they are very similar and the terminology does get mixed up, a meta box is basically a meta field, but you are right, using meta box makes it easier to add separate boxes/write panels. The functions to use them are the same.

Comment: **NOTE:** Callback functions for metaboxes receive the `$post` object as the first incoming parameter(so you can extract the post ID from there if you need it).